# Why does my RecyclerView not scroll when placed inside an AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appbarlayout

I have an AppBarLayout in my app along with a FrameLayout that I use as a placeholder to load in fragments:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_content_fragment"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The fragment in question looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/loading_downloaded"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id = "@+id/items_downloaded"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Fragment is substituted in from code as you might anticipate:

```
  val fragMan: FragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
   fragMan.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_content_fragment, fragment).commit()
```

The problem is that I cannot scroll my `RecyclerView` when I format it this way. If I move the `FrameLayout` outside of the `AppBarLayout` it works perfectly but then the fragment lies behind the app bar, which is very untidy. This confirms for me that the fragment is working correctly, I just can't figure out why the fragment's scroll behaviour changes when it's within the `AppBarLayout`.

What do I need to do to be able to scroll my content? Or have I misunderstood and I need to display my fragments outside the `AppBarLayout` where they scroll correctly and shift everything down by the height of the app bar?

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment's content is meant to be placed as a sibling of the `AppBarLayout`. You should wrap everything inside a `CoordinatorLayout` and set this attribute in your `FrameLayout` where your fragment resides: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

Here's your XML structure would be:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <FrameLayout 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" ... > 
        ... 
    </FrameLayout>
    <AppBarLayout> ... </AppBarLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Having this setup would allow your fragment to show all of it's views with your `AppBarLayout`. `CoordinatorLayout` will take care of everything for you.

Here's the official documentation:

> AppBarLayout also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to
>   know when to scroll. The binding is done through the
>   AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior behavior class, meaning that you
>   should set your scrolling view's behavior to be an instance of
>   AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior. A string resource containing the
>   full class name is available.

See this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html